# How to have one socket id when one client connect to socket server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket

Im getting two socket id when im connecting to node socket server through react.js.When im opening one tab in my server console two id are getting displayed.

Server Code
`

```
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const httpServer = createServer();
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors: {
        origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
      methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});

io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
  console.log(socket.id);
  console.log("Message");
})

httpServer.listen(2000);`
```

Client Code

```
`import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

function App() {
  const [val,changeVal]=useState("Checking");
  const socket=io('http://localhost:2000/');

  socket.on('message',(message)=>{
    console.log(message);
    changeVal(message.firstname);

  })
    const h1ClickHandler=()=>{
        console.log("message");
    }
  return (
    <div className="App">
   <h1 onClick={h1ClickHandler}> {val} </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using create-react-app, if so, it's using by default StricMode, it redreing components twice, to highlighting potential problems in your application, you can disable it by removing <React.StrictMode> in your index.js ( in your root project )
you can read more about it in the doc:
[1]: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Comment: now it is displaying 3 ids after doing this

Comment: restart your dev servers backend and frontend, it's should display one id.